# Why is Xcode 4.5 failing to refresh provisioning profiles? Also won't add devices to portal

Tags: xcode, osx-mountain-lion, provisioning-profile, iphone-developer-program

I'm running Xcode 4.5 on Mountain Lion. Every time I try to refresh my provisioning profiles I get an error stating "The data couldn’t be read because it has been corrupted." I get the same response when attempting to add a new device to the developer portal.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Xcode 4.5 fails to auto-update my team provisioning profile. Clicking "Refresh" appears to be syncing the data with the Provisioning Portal, but at the end I get an error message: "You are not allowed to perform this operation. Please check with one of your team admins, or, if you need further assistance, please contact Apple Developer Program Support."

The only solution I found is to create a new profile in the Provisioning Portal, add the devices I want to that profile and use that profile instead of the team profile.

Comment: I'm not getting an error... it simply fails to update my profile. Seems like XCode 4.5 hates the team provisioning profile

Comment: any solution with regards to this one? I seem to have the same kind of problem.

Comment: @100grams, i am not having the error that OP is having, but the exact same error as you are. Have you found any solution other than creating a new provisioning profile? My problem is that i am already using a custom provisioning profile. If you have any input, please reply here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13350545

Answer (score -1):

This is not a real answer but a workaround.
(I have the same error and also a new clean install of Mountain Lion does not help)

- Go to developer.apple.com/membercenter/
- choose "iOS ProvisioningPortal"
- under "certificates" you can create, download and install your developer certificate to "keychain access"
- under "Provisioning" you can download and install all the files you need to your xcode "provisioning profiles"

-> so you should have the same result as if "refresh" works

Comment: You are right. This is not a real answer. Apple seams to ignore bad user experience since I got this issue about a year or so. The bigger problem is that my profile (which is managed by Xcode) is not renewable.