# Xcode Organizer - cannot refresh Provisioning Profiles list

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, provisioning-profile

I am using Xcode 4.3.3

Everything used to work fine before, but since couple of months ago, I can no longer refresh provisioning profiles through Organizer.

**The problem:**

- I open organizer
- Click Provisioning Profiles at the top
- Then click "Refresh" button at the bottom right"

  1. It displays "Downloading development certificates..." and prompts to login.
  2. After successful login, it displays "Fetching team list..." then shows the error:
     *"You are not allowed to perform this operation. Please check with one of your Team Admins, or, if you need further assistance, please contact Apple Developer Program Support"*

**Some more information:**

- I **am** Team Admin
- I have valid developer certificate, as displayed in both the Apple Developer Portal, my Keychain, and in Organizer (like i said, this all used to work)
- I have several valid provisioning profiles displayed in Organizer.
- I have 2 teams displayed in organizer:

  1. One with developement developer certificate (mine)
  2. One with distribution certificate (for app store)
- This is not a password issue (I get a different error when i type the wrong password)
- I have removed all other developer certificates besides mine and the distribution certificate
- I can successfully add certificates if i manually download them
- I can successfully add provisioning profiles if i manually download them
- In the Apple Developer Portal, there are no provisioning profiles marked as "Invalid" (there are some that are expired however)
- I have force-quit Xcode and even restarted the Mac

This started happening sometime after iOS6 got released (definitely not at the same time). I've read similar questions on the subject, but most of them deal with "corrupted data" error message. This is not the case for me.

**UPDATE 1 (Nov 13)**

I have now done the following:

- I have removed all certificates from Keychain, including public and private key.
- I've revoked my certificate in Apple Dev Portal.
- I've restarted the machine.
- I opened Xcode again and hit refresh:

  1. it asked me to login, and prompted to submit a request for a new certificate.
  2. The new certificate was successfully approved and issued, and downloaded into my keychain (i see new public and private keys, as well as the cert).

However i am still getting the same error on the "refresh" of provisioning profiles: "*You are not allowed to perform this operation*" and i have no profiles in organizer.

**UPDATE 2 (Nov 13)**

- I've now updated to XCode 4.5
- On the first refresh, it actually worked.
- On all subsequent refreshes, it fails with the same error message *"You are not allowed to perform this operation. Please check with one of your Team Admins, or, if you need further assistance, please contact Apple Developer Program Support"*, however it now does it after "Generating Mac Team Provisioning Profile"

  1. Please note i am not using Mac Development. I don't have Developer Mode Enabled, and i don't have Mac Developer program.
  2. I have tried with and without Mac Developer Mode enabled.
  3. Despite the same vague error message, it actually seems to be updating the iOS provisioning profiles.

After so much time on this, i am still determined to remove this error message. Maybe someone can assist and tell me where XCode would keep it's application log? Is there anything like windows "Event Viewer" for a Mac?

Comment: Has this changed in Xcode 6? From the steps in the question - after I open Organizer I don't see "Click Provisioning Profiles at the top"

Comment: @SnowCrash yes it's different with the latest Xcode

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favourite company](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try Xcode 5.1. It looks like Apple finally fixed this issue.

Comment: Well, none of the useful tips managed to resolve it. I did not update my Xcode yet, however the problem seems to have disappeared around the time that iOS7 came out. I am accepting this answer as (although not fully spot on), it was correct in identifying the issue that's only under Apple control

Answer (score 4):

I was also getting this error "You are not allowed to perform this operation. Please check with one of your Team Admins, or, if you need further assistance, please contact Apple Developer Program Support". My developer provisioning was not working so I could not even test my apps on device.

Here's what worked for me:

- Go on the iOS Provisioning Portal > Certificates > Development. There is probably a Certificate there which you no longer have the key pair for in Keychain. Revoke it.
- Delete the relevant profiles from the Xcode organizer. Quit Xcode.
- Go to ~Library/Developer/Xcode and delete connect1.apple.com **.db (maybe not necessary, but won't hurt).
- Go to ~Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode and delete the Cache* files.

Now, Xcode is supposed to automatically create a new developer cert, but that seems to be broken right now. So, don't try to use it. Instead:

- Go back to the iOS Provisioning Portal.
- Make sure that your development certificate is revoked (so you don't have one).
- Now Create a new one, and use the manual process which involves using keychain (we're back in 2009 here). Download the cert.
- Go back to Xcode > Organizer. Plug in your device. Click on "Provisioning Profiles" under your device name. Delete all certificates currently on the device.
- Click on the device name. Click "Add to Portal" at the bottom. Go through that process.
- Go back to Library > Provisioning Profiles (at the top left). If you have an extra Team Provisioning Profile that is invalid, delete it.

Now you should have a working system.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem. The reason was the wrong Apple ID please check your Apple Id in the dev center https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/urlRedirect.action?mode=update_profile&userAction=updateAccount&cancelPath=/devcenter/ios/index.action&successPath=/devcenter/ios/index.action

Comment: I wish this would be it, however this is not the case. I only have 1 Apple ID, and this is the one that I use in Xcode.  Please note that as I've stated in Update 2, I am currently getting the list of iOS provisioning profiles updated (this wouldn't have happened if Apple ID was wrong), but the error still happens right after "Generating Mac Team Provisioning Profile". For some reason, it thinks I need the Mac programme stuff, which I don't have and never had.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue. I just deleted all the profiles from the Xcode and then restarted it. Afterwards it prompted for Apple Id credentials and all things were in place (with modified profiles).

Comment: I have tried this. Removing all provisioning profiles from XCode and then restarting didn't help. I still get the same error message. I am afraid to remove my certificates from Keychain.

Comment: does your keychain has the relevant certificates (private key and the one you downloaded from iOS dev portal)?

Comment: I have now removed both, my developer certificate and the distribution certificate from Keychain... still the same error

Comment: How come it should be same! your Xcode should not be able to add profiles manually too.

Comment: I have removed all certificates from Keychain, including public and private key. I've revoked my certificate in Apple Dev Portal. I've restarted the machine. I opened Xcode again and hit refresh: it asked me to login, and prompted to submit a request for a new certificate. The new certificate was successfully approved and issued, and downloaded into my keychain (i see new public and private keys, as well as the cert). However i am still getting the same error on the "refresh" of provisioning profiles: "You are not allowed to perform this operation" and i have no profiles in organizer.

Answer (score 2):

Actually solution pretty strange.

Looks like you must be member of Mac Developer Program. It helped me.

**By adding my account to Mac Developer program issue was fixed!**

[Apple Discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5839152?tstart=0)

Comment: This was the solution for me as well. I was pulling my hair out all day. I was in iOS, but not in recently created Mac OS program.

Comment: Only in Apple's eyes would "paying extra $99 to be added to Mac Dev Program" be a solution

Comment: The free "Safari Developer Program" worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

delete

> **~/Macintosh HD/User/home/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles**

Comment: I will not judge the quality of the answer here, because I'm not expert in the matter but please be wise and move/rename file instead of deleting them first ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to shoot in the dark. I have never come across this issue, even though I have been juggling around a bunch of dev accounts.

Once your keychain and organizer are clean,

Try to get your mac spotlight to reindex (search something in the spotlight, select the last row), in the privacy tab, include the MacintoshHD (and any other drives indexed) in the list of locations preventing spotlight to index

repeat the steps above and remove the Macitosh HD from the same list, so that a fresh index is created.

Let me know if this makes any difference. (I had a similar issue, and this solution worked)

Comment: I've done the above steps and waited for Spotlight to finish indexing (took a long while). Then restarted the machine and tried again. No luck, same as before.

Comment: wish it helped! my only other suggestions would be to contact dev program support or upgrade to the latest xcode. (I am on 4.5)

Comment: Oh bloody heck... I've updated to 4.5 and it worked. I was so excited... but it only worked on the first refresh... all other attempts are giving me the same error again and again...

Comment: Would you know how to view some kind of application logging that Xcode would produce? Anything like windows Event Viewer?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. I've found the solution finaly.
1.Access DevCenter on "Safari".
2.Sign in by your AppleID/PW. I think you cant sign in.
3.Delete saved password in Safari, and Preference / Privacy / enable cookies.
4.If you became to able to Sign in, you can sign in on "Organizer".

I hope my poor English helps Slav and someone has the same Problem.

Comment: this is not the proper answer..please write these things in comment field.

Comment: Tried this, no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

You have to use xcode 5.1.1 or later to upload your build.